# css media query not working for specific div?

Tags: css, media-queries

To make sure the media query was actually working and the problem not being me setting the wrong max-width, I set the nav bar to change color and height when the max width was reached. My main goal was for the search bar to move further to the left but this doesn't work (the change in background color was for visual purposes). Why is this so? I'm trying to reposition the search bar as it glitches once the screen gets smaller.

```css
nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translate(16%);
}

nav ul li {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.search {
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 35px;
  transform: translate(180px, -1px);
}

.search input {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  outline: none;
  width: 0px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

search:hover input {
  width: 150px;
}

.btn {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

.btn i {
  position: Relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1380px) {
  nav {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .search {
    background-color: indigo;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#>word1</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>word2</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>word3</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
    <div class=btn>
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add more details like html in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provide all required code in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: By the way: Is the background-color changing at the breakpoint?

Comment: @biberman it's been added! The background-color only changes for nav and not .search

Comment: It also changes for search but you can't see it because the input has zero width. I will watch the rest later...

Comment: I answered your question - please give a feedback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media query is working as expected: The `background-color`s are applied and the `height` is set. The `background-color` for `.search` wasn't so good visible because the search input has a `width: 0px` - therefor i tested with `50px`. The change of the `height` wasn't visible because everything was white - therefor i tested with:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Now you can see that on big screens the nav has no `height` (= `auto`) and on small screens `40px` (use the browsers dev tools).

**Working example:**

```css
nav {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translate(16%);
}

nav ul li {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.search {
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 35px;
  transform: translate(180px, -1px);
}

.search input {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  outline: none;
  width: 0px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.search:hover input {
  width: 150px;
}

.btn {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

.btn i {
  position: Relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1380px) {
  nav {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .search {
    background-color: indigo;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#>word1</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>word2</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>word3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
    <div class=btn>
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

**Alternative example:**

with `display: flex` for the whole `nav` container and deactivated `transform` for the `ul` in the media query

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translate(16%);
}

nav ul li {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.search {
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 35px;
}

.search input {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  outline: none;
  width: 0px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.search:hover input {
  width: 150px;
}

.btn {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

.btn i {
  position: Relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1380px) {
  nav {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 40px;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    transform: none;
  }
  
  .search {
    background-color: indigo;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#>word1</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>word2</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>word3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
    <div class=btn>
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I guess it was because of this and i also found out another reason was due to `<div class=btn>
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>`was on top of .search so i wasn't able to see the changes (I did not include this in the snippet above as i thought it was irrelevant). Quick question, although this confirmed that media query does work, why does my search bar still glitch onto the next line although i moved it further left using tranform?

Comment: What do you mean with "*glitch onto the next line*"? In the stack snippet it is in the same line like `word1word2word3`...

Comment: I've edited the snippet to make it more or less identical to my original code, although hovering doesn't seem to work in the snippet.

Comment: In my stack snippet the hover effect is working. But in your snippet is a typo `search` without the dot before it...

Comment: test my alternative example that i added now

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working for all the div's, check if you forgot to put *`<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />`* inside your `<head> </head>` tags where you have your HTML code. This should do the trick.

Comment: I went back to recheck and it's already there so I don't think this is the case.